# Streaming data to response CFHTTPMessageRef possible?

Tags: objective-c, ios, streaming, cfnetwork

I know it is possible to stream data to a `CFHTTPMessageRef` that is a request object, this can be achieved by using the method `CFReadStreamCreateForHTTPRequest`.

Is it possible to do the same with a `CFHTTPMessageRef` that is a response object?

What I want to happen is that I start a thread/operation (or similar) with two parameters.
Parameter one is a request with a readstream to read the actual request.
Parameter two should be a response with preferably a write stream to write your reply in.

Obviously I can do this using a readstream and a writestream directly, however then I'd manually have to format the request and response.

Is this possible using the CFNetwork classes?

Comment: I have still not found a way to do this. The way I do it now is create a response, add headers to it. I then serialize it and stream it and afterwards I stream the body of the response separately. This way the response formats my response. It would be neater though I was able to stream data to the response directly instead of using an explicit stream.

Comment: I assume you have to know how much data you'll be sending in advance so you can set the content length header, but are you doing anything special whilst streaming the body, or just sending the raw bytes when they become available?

Comment: Well, not necessarily. If the response object was cleverly implemented it could assume chunked encoding when length was not available. Other than that I am just streaming the bytes as I get them.

Comment: Yeah I managed to get it working by streaming the bytes as soon as they were available. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't understand your question very well. but I used CFNetwork for my streaming. for receiving the response here is how I receive it:

```
-(void)stream:(NSStream *)aStream handleEvent:(NSStreamEvent)eventCode
{    
    /*
         The NSStreamEvent constant can be one of the following:
         NSStreamEventNone              -- No event has occurred.
         NSStreamEventOpenCompleted     -- The open has completed successfully.
         NSStreamEventHasBytesAvailable -- The stream has bytes to be read.
         NSStreamEventHasSpaceAvailable -- The stream can accept bytes for writing.
         NSStreamEventErrorOccurred     -- An error has occurred on the stream.
         NSStreamEventEndEncountered    -- The end of the stream has been reached. 
     */

    switch (eventCode) 
    {
        case NSStreamEventHasBytesAvailable:
            len = [(NSInputStream *)aStream read:buf maxLength:1024];
            if(len) {    
                //_data type is nsmutabledata
                [_data appendBytes:(const void *)buf length:len];
                int bytesRead;
                bytesRead += len;
            } else {
                NSLog(@"No data.");
            }
            break;
        case NSStreamEventErrorOccurred:

            break;
        case NSStreamEventOpenCompleted:

            break;
        case NSStreamEventEndEncountered:

            break;
        case NSStreamEventNone:

            break;
        case NSStreamEventHasSpaceAvailable:

            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: I understand how NSStreamEventHasBytesAvailable works and that is not really my question. My question is more about the streaming of the request and particularly about the response. It seems to be possible to read your request from a stream using the method I mentioned above. I want to know if it is possible to do the same with a response. So far I have not found any solutions for that. Imagine a web client and a web server in your program, sockets are not used but streams are. I can give the server a request object which it can read, but that is all. I have not found the client counterpart.